# Unable to start wildfly 10.1.0.Final in cluster mode when enabling IPv6

Tags: wildfly, ipv6

Currently we use wildfly 10.1.0.Final with OpenJDK 7. When I set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=false to support IpV6 as new requirement from customers. But I see this problem below in cluster mode only

What should we do now? If I set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, it is working properly, but this means that IPv6 is not supported.

Thank you!

java -version
**java version "1.7.0_79"**
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.4.el6-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Exception:

> 2017-10-06 10:35:51,667 ERROR [ServerService Thread Pool --
>   3]-[org.jboss.modcluster] MODCLUSTER000034: Failed to start advertise
>   listener: java.net.SocketException: bad argument for IP_MULTICAST_IF:
>   address not bound to any interface
>
> ```
> at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSetOption(Native Method)
>
> at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.setOption(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:310)
>
> at java.net.MulticastSocket.setInterface(MulticastSocket.java:471)
>
> at org.jboss.modcluster.advertise.impl.AdvertiseListenerImpl.init(AdvertiseListenerImpl.java:151)
>
> at org.jboss.modcluster.advertise.impl.AdvertiseListenerImpl.start(AdvertiseListenerImpl.java:165)
>
> at org.jboss.modcluster.ModClusterService.init(ModClusterService.java:178)
>
> at org.wildfly.mod_cluster.undertow.UndertowEventHandlerAdapter.start(UndertowEventHandlerAdapter.java:100)
>
> at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder$1.run(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:102)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
> ```
>
> 2017-10-06 10:35:51,797 INFO  [MSC service thread
>   1-7]-[org.jboss.as.remoting] WFLYRMT0001: Listening on [::]:9999
>
> 2017-10-06 10:35:52,014 INFO  [MSC service thread
>   1-5]-[org.jboss.as.remoting] WFLYRMT0001: Listening on [::]:4447

Comment: What multicast address are you trying to bind?

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/233410

Comment: The error is with an argument while trying to bind a multicast interface. What multicast address are you trying to bind? IPv6 multicast addresses start with `ff`, and there are flags and scope that have specific meanings.

Comment: mutiple cast: 192.168.92.204

Comment: That is an IPv4 address, and it is not a multicast address. IPv4 multicast addresses are in the `224.0.0.0/4` range, and you normally would use one from the administratively scoped multicast range of `239.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: It is 225.1.2.5

Comment: Actually, that IPv4 multicast address is in a reserved range that you are not allowed to use. The entire range from `225.0.0.0` to `231.255.255.255` is reserved. See the _[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)_.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

mutiple cast: 225.1.2.5

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:9C:DD:DC
          inet addr:192.168.92.204  Bcast:192.168.92.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe9c:dddc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:971537495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:666680550 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:468632879172 (436.4 GiB)  TX bytes:548433354959 (510.7 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:838757022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:838757022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:280155497754 (260.9 GiB)  TX bytes:280155497754 (260.9 GiB)
```

jboss.bind.address = 0.0.0.0

I see similar issue here, but not anwsered yet
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/233410